# Problems with importing Excel files in CSV format ->Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, import, tidyverse, openxlsx

I am trying to import a file using read_csv(). But when I run the line it gives me the following error:

```
path <- ('C:\\JEAC\\Cursos\\SEE Data Science\\Módulo 3\\Módulo 3_ Clustering y descubrimiento de patrones\\BD\\Cust_Segmentation.csv')
Cust_Segmentation <- read_csv(path)
```

From there I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:In file(con, "rb") : cannot open file 'C:/JEAC/Cursos/SEE Data Science/Mï¿½dulo 3/Mï¿½dulo 3_Clustering y descubrimiento de patrones/BD/Cust_Segmentation.csv': No such file or directory
```

It is important to clarify that the directory is set correctly because when I run the same code with read.csv() it works perfectly.
Can someone help me please, I'm desperate

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the accents in the directory names, but I cannot reproduce with that alone. I created a directory and csv file named `"Módulo 3_ Clustering y descubrimiento de patrones\\mt.csv"` and it worked with both `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv`. (I also named the *file* with the `"Módulo....csv"` filename, still no problem.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be to the default encoding of `read_csv()`. You could try playing around with the encoding:

```
path <- 'C:\\JEAC\\Cursos\\SEE Data Science\\Módulo 3\\Módulo 3_ Clustering y descubrimiento de patrones\\BD\\Cust_Segmentation.csv'
Cust_Segmentation <- readr::read_csv(file = path, locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Although I would recommend to stay away from using special characters in paths or files, since it is always prone to errors, especially when sharing code.